# Arranging the letters of the word EDUCATION, so that the following conditions hold

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> How many ways to arrange the letters of the word EDUCATION, so that the following conditions hold:
>
> - The vowels occur in the same order
> - The consonants occur in the same order
> - no two consonants are next to each other

My approach:

Suppose I arrange the consonants and so it looks like
             _D_C_T_N_
Now we need to arrange the vowels in the same order as they occur in the original word(they are being placed in the **underscores**)

Now, note that there are $5$ underscores and total no. of vowels $=5$

So, the problem boils down to the following:

> Find all integer solutions to the equation:$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=5,$$
>   where $x_2,x_3,x_4$ are **not equal to $0$**

I said that $x_2,x_3,x_4$ are **not equal to $0$**, because **no two consonants are next to each other**, but $x_1$ and $x_5$ can be $0$.

Now this is a modification of the famous Stars and Bars problem. How to go from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to use unmodified stars and bars by considering the *vowels* first:

```
_E_U_A_I_O_
```

where each underscore may hold at most one consonant. Immediately we see that the answer to the question is $\binom64=15$.

Comment: Perfect...but what is the problem with my approach?

Comment: @amityas Your approach places differing constraints on the variables, so it can't be handled as elegantly.

Comment: What answer do I get on finding all integer solutions to the equation:$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=5,$$
where $x_2,x_3,x_4$ are **not equal to $0$**

Comment: @amityas Fifteen. Define new variables $x'_2,x'_3,x'_4$ by subtracting one from their un-primed counterparts, then you have an equation with all variables nonnegative but possibly zero: $x_1+x'_2+x'_3+x'_4+x_5=2$. There are fifteen solutions to this reduced equation.

Comment: What do you mean by 'un-primed counterparts'?

Comment: @amityas $x'_2=x_2-1$, $x'_3=x_3-1$, $x'_4=x_4-1$. The new variables, those with primes ($'$), can be 0.

Comment: This you have already told me in your previous comment.

Comment: @amityas What, trite! The un-primed counterpart of $x'_2$ is $x_2$, and so on.

Comment: So why are we "Defining  new variables $x′2,x′3,x′4x2′,x3′,x4′$ by subtracting one from their un-primed counterparts"?

Comment: @amityas With those new variables, the resulting equation can be directly analysed using stars and bars. I said it was inelegant because the method I used in the answer body is shorter.

Comment: I misunderstood something... Do you want to say that my eq. and your eq. are equivalent, and the solution to both of them is $15$?

Comment: @amityas Yes.${}$

Comment: ...Thank you very much...